# How to point frontend towards local backend server for local testing

Tags: frontend, localhost, web-development-server, manual-testing

I'm developing a full-stack web app, which has both a frontend and a backend. In production, my frontend will be hosted at `https://frontend.com`, and my backend at `https://backend.com`. It seems reasonable to hardcode the address `https://backend.com` in my frontend code.

However, when I am testing the app locally, I'll want to spin up the backend at, say, `localhost:8000`, and redirect my frontend to this address instead. My question is: **what's the easiest/most elegant way to do this?**

One approach is to manually change the frontend code to point to `localhost:8000` for local testing, and then change it back before deploying. However, this is quite annoying, and it's too easy to forget to change it back.

An approach I've used in the past is:

1. Create a file `server.js` containing:

   ```js
   const LOCAL_SERVER = "http://localhost:8000"
   ```
2. Import this file in my frontend HTML:

   ```html
   <script src="server.js"></script>
   ```
3. Set a fallback to the remote/production server in my JS scripts:

   ```js
   let SERVER = typeof LOCAL_SERVER === 'undefined' ? 'https://backend.com' : LOCAL_SERVER
   ```
4. Add `server.js` to my `.gitignore`.

This works, but it feels kind of hacky, and it pollutes my production code with references to this (possibly non-existent) `server.js` and `LOCAL_SERVER` constant. **I'm wondering if anyone has a better way.**

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If your real backend & local backend use the same port, a simple solution is to add the following line to your `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   backend.com
```

Comment: Just tried to do this, and my browser is giving me `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR: invalid response`. Maybe it doesn't work after all?